# Unicode character: cart

Tags: unicode, utf-8

Does someone know a unicode character for a shopping cart (or similar)? I found pizza(U+1F355), hotline(U+2706) and what ever this is(U+26A7), but no damn shopping cart!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is none, so far. If there were, it would undoubtedly have the word SHOPPING in its name, and then http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm would find it under that name, but it doesn’t.

Not a big issue really. It generally takes over ten years from the adoption of a new character into Unicode before it is reasonably widely available in commonly used fonts. For example, U+1F355 SLICE OF PIZZA is available on approximately one font (which is not included in any operating system or commonly used software distribution).

Answer (score 13):

Worth noting: Unicode 9.0 and Emoji 3.0: Shopping Trolley "" (U+1F6D2)

http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-released.html#1f6d2

Answer (score 2):

Today (2015's) the [Font-Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/) is popular and have some options of shopping-carts. Ex: fa-shopping-cart

You need to import the font in your CSS.

Answer (score -2):

Try Unicode: f07a  http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/shopping-cart/

I have not tested this, but found it on the website above, good luck!

Comment: Hint - this will only work, if one includes the font-awesome fonts.

Comment: 0xe000 to 0xf8ff is private use, apparently.

Answer (score -2):

&#xe116  this unicode s as per W3schools.com

Comment: 0xe000 to 0xf8ff is private use, apparently.